# What is in the protein bars in the Snowpiercer?

Tags: plot-explanation, snowpiercer

Yesterday I watched [Snowpiercer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706620/?ref%5f=nv%5fsr%5f1) and somehow I was a bit curious as to what was in the protein bars they made. It looked like insects.

Comment: Was it explained in the movie? If not, why would any of us have a "correct" answer as opposed to a "speculative" answer?

Comment: Because maybe saw it clearly in the movie. I didn't

Comment: @MeatTrademark It was explained in the movie and the OP simply missed it. While that doesn't need to make it a particualrly good question, it definitely makes it a perfectly on-topic plot-explanation question. And if it happened to be not shown in the movie, then well, it's still a perfectly on-topic plot-explanation question, just with the simple *"unfortunately that isn't answered in the movie"*-answer. Request immediate reopening.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Okay. I'm pretty easy-going and often retract my VTC's even without petition. I only voted to close after it came up in my review. VTR'ed.

Comment: @MeatTrademark Haha, no problem, the close-vote wasn't *entirely* ungrounded. But I'm glad I could convince you of the opposite. In return I'll try to be more lenient on crappy ID questions. ;-)

Comment: I just saw the movie and a lot of it was filmed with pretty dark tones.  I couldn't really make out what was shown to be in the protein bars, either.

Comment: I was wondering what the protein bars were also. Upon opening the 'hopper' i had to rewind, because it looked like crabs to me. P. S. How did the train not derail in 18 years? That's what i thought.

Comment: In real life, they are sweet red (adzuki) bean paste jelly bars. Delicious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The protein bars in Snowpiercer use **Insects** as their primary ingredient, much to Curtis' Horror.

[image]

Known as Entomophagy, the practice is actually not uncommon, as insects are used in diets  around the globe.

There are plenty of Dystopian Entomophagic possibilities's being actively discussed right now, as some prominent researchers believe humanity's acceptance of an insect based diet is a key milestone to [global sustainability.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3012052/)

Comment: In fact I don't think entomophagy would actually be a dystopia rather than a utopia, as I tend to agree with those mentioned *"many scientists"* (even if not being an expert on the topic myself).

Comment: Insect diet, huh? **I vote non-sustainable extinction.**

Comment: I'm not sure why Curtis was so horrified by the bugs, considering what he admitted to eating later in the movie!

Comment: So true. It looked like insects to me as well, but the actors' reactions to it seemed more like straight out of Soylent Green.

Comment: The future is here! You can eat insect protein bars now! http://exoprotein.com/

Comment: Reminds me of the old joke; "What do Ethiopians and Yoko Ono have in common?"

Answer (score 8):

The film's [final draft screenplay](http://scriptdrive.net/attachment.php?aid=2029) (registration required) indicates that the bars are made from ground up **cockroaches**:

> **CURTIS’ POV:** ***the tank is full of millions of cockroaches***, interlocked in a hellish vision of crawling, squirming movement. They
>   seem to be cannibalizing one another. Crushed body parts are visible.
>   The cockroaches are fed into a grinder that turns them to black
>   powder.